# Need a tweak in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Tbl 1

ID Name Email
1  A    a@b.c
2  B    b@c.d

Tbl2

ID Related_ID Value Name
1  1          Z     Name1
2  1          Y     Name2
3  2          X     Name1
4  2          W     Name2
5  2          G     Name3
```

I can write a query to show

```
ID Name Email Value1
1  A    a@b.c Z
1  A    a@b.c Y
```

How can I write it so it will become like

```
ID Name Email Value1 Value2
1  A    a@b.c Z      Y
2  B    b@c.d X      W
```

Comment: Will you only ever have two values?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you give a bit of background please, it may help us arrive at a better answer.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to de-normalize the data??

Comment: yea, coz The database structure is not from me. And I am trying to use the existing database structure from a system to write some custom functions.

Comment: You would have to do a self join to get that second value column.  As Shark said though, why denormalize the data?  You should likely be processing it different, not pulling it from the database differently.

Comment: @Corbin, I dun get it by process it different, not pulling it from db differently.. can u explain a bit?

Comment: @william the existing database structure is good: it's normalized data.  You're try to denormalize it with your desired result set.  There's very few scenarios that denormalizing data is a good idea.

Comment: Instead of trying to pull a second column that represents a second row, why not process it as two rows at the application level?

Comment: @Corbin is right.  The application should be handling the normalized data just fine.  If you are using .NET I can help out with the code/logic for the application.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using PIVOT Statement.
Here are a couple of links you can have a look at.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get what you want using dynamic sql.

Note that the CTE test and the temporary table #tmp2 should map to your original tables.

```
create table #tmp (ID int, Related_ID int, Value nvarchar(50), Name nvarchar(50), rn int)
delete #tmp

create table #tmp2 (ID int, Name nvarchar(50), Email nvarchar(50))
delete #tmp2

;with test(ID, Related_ID, Value, Name)
as
(
select 1,  1,          'Z',     'Name1'
union all
select 2,  1,          'Y',     'Name2'
union all
select 3,  2,          'X',     'Name1'
union all
select 4,  2,          'W',     'Name2'
union all
select 5,  2,          'G',     'Name3'
)

insert into #tmp
select *, row_number() OVER (partition by Related_ID order by ID) as rn
from test

insert into #tmp2
select 1,  'A',    'a@b.c'
union all
select 2,  'B',    'b@c.d'


declare @d nvarchar(MAX)
        ,@e nvarchar(MAX)

SET     @d = 'select a.ID, a.Name, a.Email '
SET     @e =   ',min(case b.rn when >rn< then Value else null end) as [Value>rn<]'

select  @d = @d + (
select t from(
select  distinct replace(@e,'>rn<', b.rn) as [text()]
from    #tmp b
for xml path('')) c(t)
)

set     @d = @d + '
from    #tmp2 a
join    #tmp b
    on  a.ID = b.Related_ID
  group by a.ID, a.Name, a.Email'

exec sp_executesql @d

drop table #tmp
drop table #tmp2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t1 table(id int, name varchar(20), email varchar(32)) 
declare @t2 table(id int, related_id int, value varchar(10), name varchar(10))

insert @t1 values(1,'A', 'a@b.c')
insert @t1 values(2,'B', 'b@c.d')

insert @t2 values(1, 1, 'Z', 'Name1')
insert @t2 values(2, 1, 'Y', 'Name2')
insert @t2 values(3, 2, 'X', 'Name1')
insert @t2 values(4, 2, 'W', 'Name2')
insert @t2 values(5, 2, 'G', 'Name3')

;with a as
(
select value, related_id, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY related_id order by value desc) rn
from @t2
), b as
(
select value, related_id, rn from a where rn in (1,2)
)
select t5.ID, t5.Name, t5.Email, t3.value Value1,  t4.value Value2 
from @t1 t5
join b t3
on t3.related_id = t5.id and t3.rn = 1
join b t4
on t4.related_id = t5.id and t4.rn = 2
```

Result:

```
ID     Name       Email  Value1   Value2
------ ------ ---------- -------- ----------
1      A      a@b.c      Z        Y
2      B      b@c.d      X        W
```